# date-literal-based immediately-precedes construction

Tags: sparql, owl

I have triples asserting that two different people (B and C) each have one patient role.  These roles are realized in three healthcare encounters each.  There's a process boundary that starts each encounter and a time measurement datum that's about each process boundary.  The time measurement datums have `xsd:date` values asserted with predicate `ns1:TURBO_0010094`.  See end of post.

I would like to construct a timeline, in which each health care encounter can precede a maximum of one other encounter "belonging" to the same person.  I have a statement that constructs "encounter X precedes encounter Y" statements, but it obvious generates the following (using some *ad-hoc* abbreviation):

- HCE_B1 precedes HCE_B2
- HCE_B1 precedes HCE_B3
- HCE_B2 precedes HCE_B3

I only want to say

- HCE_B1 precedes HCE_B2
- HCE_B2 precedes HCE_B3

Any chance this can be done in a single `construct` statement?  Here's what I have so far:

```
PREFIX obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/>
PREFIX ns1: <http://transformunify.org/ontologies/>
construct {
    ?hce1 obo:BFO_0000063 ?hce2
}
WHERE {
    ?person rdf:type obo:NCBITaxon_9606 .
    ?patrole rdf:type obo:OMRSE_00000011 ;
             obo:RO_0000052 ?person .
    ?hce1 rdf:type obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
          obo:BFO_0000055 ?patrole .
    ?hce2 rdf:type obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
          obo:BFO_0000055 ?patrole .
    ?procbound1 rdf:type obo:BFO_0000035 ;
                obo:RO_0002223 ?hce1 .
    ?procbound2 rdf:type obo:BFO_0000035 ;
                obo:RO_0002223 ?hce2 .
    ?tmd1 rdf:type obo:IAO_0000416 ;
          obo:IAO_0000136 ?procbound1 ;
          ns1:TURBO_0010094 ?dateval1 .
    ?tmd2 rdf:type obo:IAO_0000416 ;
          obo:IAO_0000136 ?procbound2 ;
          ns1:TURBO_0010094 ?dateval2 .
    filter(?dateval2 > ?dateval1)
}
```

Data:

```
prefix obo: <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/> 
prefix ns1: <http://transformunify.org/ontologies/> 
prefix ns2: <http://example.org/temporality_support/>
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 


obo:HTN_00000010
  a obo:NCBITaxon_9606 ;
  rdfs:label "Basil" .

obo:HTN_00000011
  a obo:NCBITaxon_9606 ;
  rdfs:label "Clara" .

obo:HTN_00000019
  a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000029 ;
  rdfs:label "Basil's first health care encounter" .

obo:HTN_00000029
  a obo:OMRSE_00000011 ;
  obo:RO_0000052 obo:HTN_00000010 ;
  rdfs:label "Basil's patient role" .

obo:HTN_00000020
  a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000029 ;
  rdfs:label "Basil's second health care encounter" .

ns2:9be7ae98-44f6-4d95-9938-4a91e1ade556
  a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000029 ;
  rdfs:label "Basil's third health care encounter" .

ns2:c75d9821-fa00-449c-9d0b-791c1bbbc07e
  a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
  obo:RO_0002223 ns2:9be7ae98-44f6-4d95-9938-4a91e1ade556 ;
  rdfs:label "B HCE 3 start" .

ns2:ed7bbf74-60c3-4fd7-b46f-d3fa1771e219
  a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
  obo:IAO_0000136 ns2:c75d9821-fa00-449c-9d0b-791c1bbbc07e ;
  ns1:TURBO_0010094 "2019-01-22"^^xsd:date ;
  rdfs:label "B HCE 3 start date" .

obo:HTN_00000023
  a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000030 ;
  rdfs:label "Clara's first health care encounter" .

obo:HTN_00000030
  a obo:OMRSE_00000011 ;
  obo:RO_0000052 obo:HTN_00000011 ;
  rdfs:label "Clara's patient role" .

ns2:5121d5e2-41ed-48e1-9253-0aa1830c3f00
  a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000029 ;
  rdfs:label "Clara's third health care encounter" .

ns2:bc09fab9-76fb-4072-af37-f52b49ba9c64
  a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
  obo:RO_0002223 ns2:5121d5e2-41ed-48e1-9253-0aa1830c3f00 ;
  rdfs:label "C HCE 3 start" .

ns2:881afd3a-cf77-4365-b54f-6c7c99fd1e4b
  a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
  obo:IAO_0000136 ns2:bc09fab9-76fb-4072-af37-f52b49ba9c64 ;
  ns1:TURBO_0010094 "2019-01-23"^^xsd:date ;
  rdfs:label "C HCE 3 start date" .

obo:HTN_00000025
  a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000030 ;
  rdfs:label "Clara's second health care encounter" .

ns2:IAO_0000416_2
  a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
  obo:IAO_0000136 ns2:BFO_0000035_2 ;
  ns1:TURBO_0010094 "2019-01-15"^^xsd:date ;
  rdfs:label "B HCE 2 start date" .

ns2:BFO_0000035_2
  a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
  obo:RO_0002223 obo:HTN_00000020 ;
  rdfs:label "B HCE 2 start" .

ns2:IAO_0000416_3
  a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
  obo:IAO_0000136 ns2:BFO_0000035_3 ;
  ns1:TURBO_0010094 "2019-01-09"^^xsd:date ;
  rdfs:label "C HCE 1 start date" .

ns2:BFO_0000035_3
  a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
  obo:RO_0002223 obo:HTN_00000023 ;
  rdfs:label "C HCE 1 start" .

ns2:IAO_0000416_4
  a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
  obo:IAO_0000136 ns2:BFO_0000035_4 ;
  ns1:TURBO_0010094 "2019-01-16"^^xsd:date ;
  rdfs:label "C HCE 2 start date" .

ns2:BFO_0000035_4
  a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
  obo:RO_0002223 obo:HTN_00000025 ;
  rdfs:label "C HCE 2 start" .

ns2:IAO_0000416_7
  a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
  obo:IAO_0000136 ns2:BFO_0000035_7 ;
  ns1:TURBO_0010094 "2019-01-08"^^xsd:date ;
  rdfs:label "B HCE 1 start date" .

ns2:BFO_0000035_7
  a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
  obo:RO_0002223 obo:HTN_00000019 ;
  rdfs:label "B HCE 1 start" .
```

Comment: You state that each patrole have 3 encounters, so why object is `obo:HTN_00000029` in 
 `ns2:5121d5e2-41ed-48e1-9253-0aa1830c3f00  obo:BFO_0000055 obo:HTN_00000029`
instead of `obo:HTN_00000030`?

Comment: Also you may use `FILTER NOT EXISTS` about a some third ?hce instance which ?dateval is greater than ?dateval1 but less than ?dateval2

Comment: True, I'd also use `FILTER NOT EXISTS` to filter out the redundant (w.r.t. transitivity) relations.

Comment: Something like that: `filter not exists {
          ?hce3 a obo:OGMS_0000097 ;
          obo:BFO_0000055 ?patrole .
          ?procbound3 a obo:BFO_0000035 ;
                obo:RO_0002223 ?hce3 .
          ?tmd3 a obo:IAO_0000416 ;
          obo:IAO_0000136 ?procbound3 ;
          ns1:TURBO_0010094 ?dateval3 .
          filter(?dateval2 > ?dateval3 && ?dateval3 > ?dateval1)
    }` - there might be more efficient ways indeed.

Comment: This is good.  A very similar query generated 19,161 "precedes" statements from 20,524 encounters in 1m 29s.  My encounter dates don't contain a time portion, so I guess this statement doesn't account for situations in which `dateval2 = ?dateval1`.  I'll work on that soon.